# Do questions posted on the weekend get less attention?

Tags: support, questions, views, faq-proposed

Is there any statistical evidence that questions which are posted on the weekend get less attention than those posted during the work week?

Comment: Everything on meta just gets drowned in [tag:documentation] related questions the last 3 days.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ true - this question is just for future reference. I don't care how much attention it gets, that's why I post it on the weekend :)

Comment: ^ awesome idea! Somehow I have a bad perception that this doc stuff is seriously broken as presented now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ off-topic, but to funny to not to share: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png

Comment: /OT Yes, I said earlier I don't want to opt out completely, but I'm considering more and more.

Comment: Still /OT: May be documentation could be considered as the _new rep wh**re's getho_ or _rep farmer's heaven_, as I mentioned earlier elsewhere. At least they would go scrimmaging there.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No, the number of views for a question is independent from the moment of posting. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers) are some tips to attract more attention to your question; posting during the work week will not help.

---

#### Full answer

It is common knowledge that Stack Overflow sees less traffic during the weekends than during the workweek. After all, most of our users use Stack Overflow for work-related issues, and have other priorities in the weekend. Users with [>25k reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) have access to the [site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics); mere mortals can check the stats via [Quantcast](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#/trafficCard): at the time of writing, 7 million views during the weekend and three times as much, 21 million views, on working days.

Does that mean a question posted on the weekend will attract (on average) less attention? Assuming that a fixed percentage of those views are directed towards new questions, the weekend has the advantage that there are fewer questions posted, so your question stays longer on the front page. The numbers tell the story, so let's dig into the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) and find out.

We take a sample period from a couple of months ago; the Data Explorer is refreshed once a week and newer questions may not yet have the chance to 'ripe'. To account for the different timezones, we group the questions into one-hour buckets, and compute the average view count and the total number of questions in the bucket. To remove the effect that a single very popular question might have, we ignore all [outliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier) more than twice the standard deviation away from the average.

When we're done, we get the following graph:

[image]

While the number of questions is clearly higher during working days (and during European and American office hours), **the amount of views a question eventually collects is independent from the moment of posting.**

---

For reference, here is the full SQL for the [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516244/number-of-views-per-question-based-on-creation-date-time?StartDate=2015-10-01&EndDate=2015-10-15):

```sql
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = ##StartDate:string##;
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = ##EndDate:string##;

CREATE TABLE #temp (bucket datetime, average float, std float)

INSERT INTO #temp 
SELECT 
  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0),
  avg(viewcount),
  stdev(viewcount)
  FROM posts
  WHERE posttypeid = 1
    AND creationdate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
  GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0)
  ORDER BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0)
  
SELECT
  dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0) AS 'Bucket',
  avg(viewcount) AS 'Average view count',
  count(*) AS 'Number of questions'
  FROM posts INNER JOIN #temp
   ON dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0) = bucket
  WHERE posttypeid = 1
    AND creationdate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
    AND viewcount BETWEEN average - 2 * std AND average + 2 * std
  GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0)
  ORDER BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, creationdate), 0)
```

Comment: Wow, that weekly difference is really stark, more than I thought (but not more than makes sense, in hindsight). I guess I'm one of a few using SO for fun rather than to get my work done for me ^_^ (or purely as a procrastination technique during the week)

Comment: Daily minimum at about 0100 hours UTC?

Comment: What happened that 14 October? There was a party?

Comment: But it's important to realise that your question may get answered relatively later. Isn't it?

Comment: @TheMaster only to the people who are not using the site selfishly. You have to wonder who is more likely to be asking a question in the weekend. People doing homework, I would say.