# Time-zone may result in never-answered questions due to not as many users online

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions

I think that the majority of the users of Stack Overflow probably come from one specific time zone.

So when a user which is not in this specific time zone asks a question it may not get answered because not as many users are awake / online to answer it.

So it may be helpful if questions that are not answered within a certain time gets to be shown again on top of questions when the amount of users has increased. Thus, the question is more likely to be answered by more users since more users are available.

Comment: Why would you assume that the majority of users come from one time zone? We have users from all over the world. Also, this automatic reshowing of unanswered questions already happens.

Comment: Well since there are more populated time zones and not so populated time zones, combined with time zones where access to internet and education needed is not as frequent as in others

Comment: But then, there would be fewer programmers asking questions in those relatively unpopulated and technologically unsophisticated time zones, so the problem that you're describing would not occur.

Comment: Okay but one may still ask and still not get an answer as one who asks in a populated time zone.

Comment: @Kev1n91 You can ask and not get in answer even in the times of day with the highest activity.

Comment: This is already kind of implemented in the form of [Community bumping old questions with zero-score answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285978/community-modified-posts-appearing-on-homepage). Your feature request would be to also make it bump questions without any answers at all.

Comment: @Servy sure, but it is more likely to get an answer

Comment: @Kev1n91 What's your basis for that assertion?  You have yet to support it.

Comment: @Servy Sadly, only from own experience. When I post questions to the normal working hours at my country It will mostly not get answered, however if I post it at night the answers come in easier and faster. Secondly: https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com#generalInterestsCard 
At geographic iit is shwon that the majority of people come from the US

Comment: @Kev1n91 A handful of questions isn't exactly very compelling evidence.  I don't think you really need to support the assertion that SO gets more views at certain times of day, but you certainly need to support the assertion that it has a significant effect on the answer rate.

Comment: @Servy well that's a good point, but I do not have the possibilites to check that, don't I ? If there is a way I would happily do that to proove my point

Comment: @Kev1n91 The (non-deleted) questions are all publicly available.  You have the dates that they're all posted, the numbers of answers, scores of answers, etc.  None of it is private data.

Comment: @Kev1n91: "*At geographic iit is shwon that the majority of people come from the US*" Yes. But the US consists of *more than* "one time zone". It covers 4 (across the continental US).

Comment: @NicolBolas That'S true, too. I found this map: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016 which shows that there are more or less populated areas, however it does not distinguish between time zones. It also does not provide any information about the answer rate for the time zones. But I will try to achieve more data and come back with results - but this will take some time

Comment: anyway..... I understand that it's easier to get your question seen rapidly in getting it answered rapidly... but if your question is good and interesting, it will be interesting to people for a long time and will see answers outside your hours.

Comment: Getting a question answered (or, at least, getting a *good* answer) is far more a function of the following criteria than it is timing: (1) is your question properly tagged so as to attract the relevant experts? (2) is your question well presented, with all necessary information provided? (3) is your question *interesting* ,something that experts would want to take time to think about and write an answer about? If you meet these criteria, I promise it absolutely will not matter when you ask the question. We'll find it, and we'll jump on it like rabid dogs on steak.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**TL;DR**: I don't think the problem you describe exists, at least not on a larger scale. You just might have been unlucky with a few of your questions.

---

> I think that the majority of the users of Stack Overflow probably come from one specific time zone.

Yes, that's more or less true. Stack Overflow sees significantly more traffic during European/African and American office hours.

> So when a user which is not in this specific time zone asks a question it may not get answered because not as much users are awake / online to answer it.

That might be true, but there are also fewer *questions* to compete for attention. It turns out that these effects more or less cancel out, as noted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/329144/4751173). In the graph below, you can see that there is *some* variation in the average view count, but not a real pattern.

[image: number of questions and average view count]

Now, if you ask a question in an obscure tag, and e.g. you're an Australian and most experts in that tag are located in Europe or the USA, your questions might escape their attention. However, most potential answerers browse questions by tags, and in a low-traffic tag your question will be longer on the frontpage of that particular tag.