# Is my question somehow wrong? Even included complete example

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Generally speaking, I've been having issues with displaying a horizontal scrollbar with my gridview.

I've posted several variations of this question, but I ended up deleting them because there was very little activity.

So for [my final question regarding this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430762/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-div-with-gridview), I created a complete example showing the problem I'm having. Even so, there's little activity. What else can I do?

I continued researching since I knew I would not get any help from SO. So finally, I found a link from [aspsnippets.com](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/JQuery-Scrollable-GridView-with-Fixed-Header-in-ASPNet.aspx) that could be helpful. Unfortunately, the downloadable code in this link did not match the actual demo. So I posted [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433847/something-wrong-with-code-in-aspsnippets-link), but nobody's replied.

What am I doing wrong? Am I wording the question wrong?

Comment: Sundays are often low activity. And this is a public holiday weekend in lots of countries too.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not exactly seeing an issue with the question - albeit I did simply glance at it instead of peruse.  It's Sunday which is a lull, and Monday's a holiday for most folks, so you may not get many eyes on your question for a bit.

Comment: @Makoto, there's no reason for your edit. My question was unjustly downvoted, as I knew it would.

Comment: I've removed the noise from your question.  Whether or not you feel the downvote is unjustified is immaterial from your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should a question that is meaningless without viewing an external link be closed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266909/should-a-question-that-is-meaningless-without-viewing-an-external-link-be-closed)

Comment: I usually skip questions that waste my time with unnecessary noise "Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks."

Comment: @MartinSmith that was my feeling as well initially, but the [statistics tell a different story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173).

Comment: @Glorfindel one set of statistics does. Number of views isn't important though. On a Sunday they might be repeated views by the same few people. The statistics relevant here would be number of answers and average time to answer of questions tagged asp.net/C# on a Sunday.

Comment: @MartinSmith that'd be an interesting statistic as well. Let me see if I can make a SEDE query for that.

Comment: @Glorfindel - I've done that and don't see anything backing up my original claim http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/659418/csharpaspnetquestions

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. Perhaps you could add another answer to the question I linked to?

Answer (score 8):

To reset your expectations: you aren't guaranteed to get an answer *ever*, much less within 24 hours.

Also, you didn't actually include a complete example, you *linked* to some code that you used *in your project*, so a potential answerer will have to follow that link, get that code working, and then guess what else is in your project that might be the cause of it not working.  "My code isn't working" isn't exactly an exciting question to begin with; any added activation energy required to start debugging your code further reduces your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: I didn't include a complete example in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43430762/add-horizontal-scrollbar-to-div-with-gridview)?

Comment: Please check it again. And if you're not sure which one it is, it's the one that was downvoted twice after I posted this question on meta.

Comment: @rbhatup I was referring to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433847/something-wrong-with-code-in-aspsnippets-link).  Your other one seems fine.  You could just have edited your first one, though; editing bumps the question, so people get another chance to see it.

Comment: Honestly, what else can I do with that question? It's a link with wrong code. Members just like to downvote for no reason at all.

Comment: This question has -8 downvotes. Do you really think this question merits 8 downvotes? The biggest problem is that the bums that downvoted this question went to my other questions and downvoted them also.