# Am I asking the question wrong? Did I post in the wrong community?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [aws info from empty target group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51657744/aws-info-from-empty-target-group)

I'm hardly getting any views and no responses on my question.
I'd appreciate some feedback on why that is so.
Specifically, did I post in the wrong community? And is the question clear? Was there a tag I was supposed to use and didn't?

Comment: You only chose a single and quite specific tag. That might explain the limited visibility. Also, as SO is about programming, questions with a language tag work best. Scripting questions _might_ be fine, but I don't know anything about AWS.

Comment: @pnuts common sense might suggest that, but [SEDE suggests that doesn't matter](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/329143/4751173) (at least for total views).

Comment: These tags are on the long tail of SO and are inevitably affected first by the declining participation of contributors.  All of the experts in the [aws-cli] tag are still around and visiting SO, they are however not posting answers anymore.  When participation gets too low for experts to read each other's answers then they'll move to greener pastures.  You can buy more views with a bounty, that however requires participating yourself and posting answers to earn enough rep.

Comment: @pnuts yes, it's slightly different. SEDE is not able to see on which dates those views occurred. My theory is that less visitors in the weekend also means less new/active questions, so the visibility of the remaining questions is increased and everything cancels out.

Comment: there you go - bounty for some more attention.

Comment: While this may sound somewhat counter-intuitive to SO's policies and even my own personal take on the approach to tags as in whole. Questions like that are suitable for [tag:python] as their side-tag. While I genuinely dislike when users artificially 'over-tag' their questions, in occassions like these, where a certain tag is clearly underrepresented it may (and usually is) a good idea to apply a broader tag. Something like [tag:aws-cli] is often a subset of someone's skillset, but not their primary focus (hence they are also not primarily focused on browsing such tag)

Comment: It is better to get lower views from experts than getting views from people who don't know the topic. Hence I wouldn't recommend too generic tags @Rawrplus

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt that's exactly what I was aiming at with the pre-face of my comment. I like to think of this as a trade-off in quality vs exposure. While I would in 99% of the cases go for the quality, once in a blue moon, the exposure could be so low, that you just have to bite the bullet. I actually was very conflicted with posting my original comment, because I do think of it as creating bad habits, but I do think it is a valid point to be made, that it has, whether we like it or not some merit of truth to it

Comment: bounty + meta now the question has attention. But this is not a widely used technology (I mean, not like python, xml, c ...) so people who can answer are probably rare

Comment: @pnuts I don't think time of day can ever really matter much. Either traffic to the site is low (in which case it will sit on the front page for a long time), or traffic is high (in which case it will be pushed off quickly). Either way, it will have the same total number of eyeballs in the time that it's on the front page, unless there's some change in the distribution of viewers over time.

Comment: @pnuts you can check Quancast for public stat of visits on SO, but it seems that you need a quancast account to see them. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313679/213575

Comment: @pnuts well, apparently, unless you have a Quantcast account, you can't see them. See my updated answer, with the response from Quantcast. If you have the account, the information you are asking for is readily available.

Comment: So they go from one tag to a bunch of irrelevant tags, if it's a bash script problem tag it bash script. Don't just tag a bunch of languages and hope someone answers with one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the `aws` command myself, but I would expect that lots of people who do would follow questions on ServerFault.  The command is specific to managing a server setup, so I think you might have had better results on SF.

It's on-topic on SO because it is about programming (using a very specialized tool), but SF also gets plenty of bash scripting questions.

---

Serverfault also has an [aws-cli](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/aws-cli) tag, with 184 questions (but 66 of them are unanswered).

Also a more general [amazon-web-services](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) tag with 5.4k questions which can get your question in front of people familiar with the terminology in your question.

---

However, SO has many more total question in those same tags.  SO's [aws-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-cli) has 1.4k questions, only 169 of them unanswered; a much better ratio than on SF.

SO's [amazon-web-services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-web-services) tag has 61.7k questions, but I don't have any idea what fraction of them  are crap compared to SF.  (Like software-recommendation questions asking if there's a tool to manage courseware / training content that you can set up on AWS).

**So possibly SO is the best site for this question after all**.

But more isn't always better.  Bash POSIX `sh` scripting questions (using standard commands like `find`, `xargs`, `grep`, `dd`, and so on) on unix.SE typically get *excellent* answers with plenty of detail explaining how/why the answer works.  But basic `bash` questions in general are split across SO, AskUbuntu, unix/linux.SE, and ServerFault at least.

SO because of it's long history and high population has 102.4k bash questions to unix.SE's 14.2k, but I'd definitely recommend asking on unix.SE.

---

For the `aws-cli` tag specifically, we'll need to hear from someone who's familiar with that community on SO and SF.  But **the unanswered numbers on SF are a worry, so based on just the numbers I think SO was the right place to ask**.

Answer (score 26):

[The question is unclear](http://idownvotedbecau.se/unclearquestion): the formulations are dense, overloaded with jargon and without any reference links. It also has insufficient info to answer: it's unclear what you have (your setup), what you're doing (see my comments to the question) and what you'd like to get (what kind of "URL" you're interested in).

So, it's very hard to understand for anyone without that specific expertise (whatever it is) what you want.

At the same time, it looks legit at first glance, so people are probably too intimidated by its technicality to vote to close as unclear. So they just move along.

I'm not intimidated but cannot VTC it atm because it has a bounty on it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.