# Weekend activity promotion - score and badges

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

I was wondering if there's any intention to try and raise the amount of users contributing and participating in weekend activities. I usually see a significant decrease in questions/answers and the speed of the answers too during weekends.

Perhaps it has already been stated somewhere (and I missed it) future implementation of extra-score (for example 12 points for each upvote and 18 for correct answer) or badges to praise users that contribute to their respective communities during weekends, since in average it might a bit of an extra-effort when compared to weekday.

Some people might be facing tight deadlines, let alone learning, and can't dedicate much time during the week, making it extra valuable for them to receive this help, in comparison to weekday contributions. Therefore, praising this contributors over the regular weekday ones

It would be nice to have some tags for Weekend-Contributors to recognize their effort on helping solve a late-sunday situation!

Edit: As stated by Makoto I'm missing access to site analytics and pitifully have to base this question on my pure subjective observation.

Comment: note that week-end is not the same for all the countries around the world (you may get surprised but it's true), let's not forget the different Time Zone

Comment: You may want to re-read info on "feature-request" tag - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info -  you put on the post...

Comment: I think additional badges like that are kinda over-the-top. It's not like anyone is forced to do stuff on weekends. This is kinda an analogy to the new "Thanks"-feature.

Comment: @akuzminykh While I agree nobody is forced to do anything on weekends, there is a diffrence in the amount and speed of contributions, and some people might be facing tight deadlines, let alone learning, and can't dedicate much time during the week, making it extra valuable for them to receive this help, in comparison to weekday contributions. Therefore, praising this contributors over the regular weekday ones.

Comment: Taking some major umbrage to "tight deadlines" - we're not the world's help desk; we're volunteers.  It's unfortunate that someone has an issue that they must solve with haste over the weekend, but it's not really our role to "fix" that or bridge a gap.  If anything, the gap lies with something we probably can't even tough (cultural, political, or skill-grade issues).

Comment: I understand and wouldn't want you to think its disqualifying or anything. I have been in this kind of unfortunate situations, which and the extra help I received from SO community was amazing and something that made me proud of. We're volunteers, I agree, but when someone is in a tight situation and I can help and make it easier for that person I'm very happy to belong to this community and help them.

Comment: Well @CeliusStingher, you do you.  I'm cool with you helping out over the weekends.  But I would strongly caution you to slow down your zeal; you can get burnt out trying to help everyone do everything all at once.

Comment: RE: tight deadlines https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Yes! I do agree burnout is possible and appreciate your advice, it's important to never lose focus of ones responsibilities.

Comment: Strongly related: [Do questions posted on the weekend get less attention?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329143/do-questions-posted-on-the-weekend-get-less-attention)

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't know this since you don't have access to [site analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), but site traffic evaporates on the site over the weekends and on some major holidays.

That implies that there are *fewer* questions to answer and there's not as much a need for as quick turn-around.

Only speaking for myself - these days I tend to not even touch my computer over the weekend.  I wouldn't have an incentive to use the site during that time since I have other things I could tend to (e.g. chores, other tasks, other social circles, etc).

This speaks to a point about us being **actual** volunteers - people who willingly give their time up to help someone out.  Someone else's deadlines don't apply when I have my own to concern myself with.  We're rewarded on the basis of us being volunteers with badges and internet points.  The only compensation I'd accept with helping someone on their project *otherwise* would be monetary.

I could respect the motivation to incentivize weekend participation, but there's not as many people on a given day to appreciate the effort we'd be putting in.

But you know...you could always  just...answer questions on weekends anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm getting there (site analytics) :) Contributing as much as possible

Comment: in the mysql tag are more or minus the same questions as during the week, only there are less people whpo answer, but the high reps always come and see, so no simple answer is not made.

Comment: Odd. I find I have much more time available to devote to the site on weekends. That's when I go through a lot of the Meta posts, handle the most moderator flags, etc.

Comment: Can I pressure you to expand this answer into something that I would upvote, namely calling out the objections that I know you share to Stack Overflow being regarded as a Help Desk, explaining that badges and other accomplishments aren't to reward the provision of *timely* help, but rather to reward contributions to this as a global knowledge base, thus time is irrelevant? I want to decline the proposal, but this doesn't provide quite the explicit justification that is needed to do so.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'll hazard an edit sometime tomorrow... Seems like it's worth the effort.

Comment: Maybe some time over the weekend ;-)